# nodejs applicaiton giving error "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" in windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, azure, npm, node-ffi

My Nodejs application works fine in ubuntu. When i tried to deploy the same in Windows machine it showed below error.

```
=>node server.js  
D:\home\site\wwwroot
D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\ffi\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:83
        throw e                  ^
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   
D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\ffi\node_modules\ref\build\Release\binding.node
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at bindings
```

I removed ffi module and tried npm  install ffi again in windows machine it too didnt work.

```
 => npm install ffi
D:\home\site\wwwroot
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
npm WARN package.json @ No license field.
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\2.11.2\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\2.11.2\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\ffi
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
```

Could you please provide your thought on this issue

Answer (score 7):

You can't move compiled addons across different platforms like that (much like you can't copy a Linux executable to Windows and expect to be able to execute it). You will need to `npm rebuild` in your project directory to recompile any addons after you copy your project tree to a different platform.

Answer (score 1):

The Node Module `ffi` is a native module. This error is caused by the limits of Azure WebApps, please refer to the section `Native Modules` of https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/. The doc said

> "Azure Websites does not support all native modules and might fail at
>   compiling those with very specific prerequisites."

So if you must use native module for NodeJS application, I recommend to use the Azure VM to support compiling native module.